# CRUD: Adding WHERE condition in the index action

Tags: cakephp, crud

I was studying the CRUD documentation but somehow I miss the point. I want to implement in the `index()`  action different `WHERE` conditions depending on some parameters I obtain from the URL.

Reading https://crud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html doesn't really help me. I tried this very simple code in the `index()` function:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->Crud->on('beforeFilter', function(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event) {
        $event->getSubject()->query->where([ "partner_type" => "AGENT" ]);
    });

    return $this->Crud->execute();
}
```

This means, **each call** of the `index` action should add the `WHERE` condition `partner_type = 'AGENT'` and return only those rows but all rows are returned.

What do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct event is `beforePaginate` - see the answer at [Github](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud/issues/671):

```
public function index()
{
    $this->Crud->on('beforePaginate', function(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event) {
        $event->getSubject()->query->where([ "partner_type" => "AGENT" ]);
    });

    return $this->Crud->execute();
}
```